# Efficient way to show a jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

Users on my site currently see details of a person by clicking on a link which redirects them to a new page where details of the person are displayed using PHP and MySQL. I want to change this so that when the link is clicked they see the details in a popup which appears next to the link.

Showing these details in a jQuery tooltip will be too limiting because ultimately I plan to enable the user to interact with content in the popup.

Also adding a dialog to each link when the page loads is too slow as there may be 30 or more links on the page. The 2 second or more delay before the page finishes loading is not acceptable. Links on my site are typically created inside a loop.

Is it possible to create a dialog for only the link clicked?

I am currently looking at an approach using jQuery Ajax and the jQuery position and dialog functions. I would like the solution to be as lightweight and simple as possible and to avoid any page refresh.

The code below shows what I have come up with. This code fails to even post input data when requesting data from the database using Ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Shows the links
for($id=0;$id<=80;$id++){
    echo("<a id='link$id' onclick=showPopup($id)>Click me at $id</a><br/>");
}
?>
<script>
function showPopup(id){
    // Gets input needed to return database records for the link clicked
    var myObj={};
    myObj["database"]="ajaxdb";
    myObj["sql"]="select * from names"; // A where clause here would be specific to the link
    var input = JSON.stringify(myObj);
    // Gets the data to show in the dialog using Ajax
    $.post('return_rows.php',input,function(data){
        // Data would be formated here before being assigned to the div
        // ....
        // ....
        $('div#dialog'+id).html(data);
    });
    // Shows the dialog using jQueryUI
    $(function() {
        $('a#link'+id).ready(function(){
        $('#dialog'+id).dialog();
            // Positions opened dialog relative to the clicked link.
            $('#dialog'+id).dialog('widget').position({
                my: 'right top',
                at: 'left bottom',
                of: 'a#link'+id
            });
        });
    });
    document.write("<div id='dialog'+id title='Title of dialog'+id></div>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help to get a solution which works would be much appreciated. Please note however that I am neither familiar with Ajax nor jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to request data for a particular link. Have the URL return a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object and then append it to the body using jQuery.

## For Example

```
function get_user_information(){
    $.ajax({
    url: url_that_returns_user_data.php,
    dataType: json,
    success: function(data){
        // parse the json data and append it to the body here
    },
    return false; // To avoid reloading the page
});
}
```